# PHP - file_put_contents Save file in folder

Tags: php, html, wordpress, save, file-put-contents

Trying to save an attachment from email into my server, the script I have so far works fine however, it saves the file in my wp root folder.

```
foreach ($attachments as $key => $attachment) {
    $name = $attachment['name'];
    $contents = $attachment['attachment'];
    file_put_contents($name, $contents);
}
```

How can I save the file into a different folder?

trying with this code but not working.

```
foreach ($attachments as $key => $attachment) {
    $name = $attachment['name'];
    $contents = $attachment['attachment'];
    file_put_contents(get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/email_attachments/' . $name, $contents);
}
```

Any Idea?

Comment: What exactly is not working? Please be more specific.

Comment: its not saving the file in the folder i want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Future Reference here how to find the path:

```
foreach ($attachments as $key => $attachment) {
        $name = $attachment['name'];
        $contents = $attachment['attachment'];
        file_put_contents(STYLESHEETPATH . '/email_attachments/' . $name, $contents);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're adding the path correctly, it's just that get_stylesheet_directory_uri() is for the web path : 
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_stylesheet_directory_uri

Try something like get_home_path() : 
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_home_path

Cheers!

Comment: using "get_home_path() . '/email_attachments/' . $name" just stops my script.

Comment: Can you turn on error reporting and get the error that is stopping your script? It's possible that it's a permission issue or syntax error at this point.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress#PHP_Errors.2C_Warnings.2C_and_Notices

Comment: Would love too seriously however, i dont know why my wp does not debug. I have changed debug from false to true in the wp-config but still cannot output php errors

Answer (score 0):

> You're adding the path correctly, it's just that
>   get_stylesheet_directory_uri() is for the web path :
>   https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_stylesheet_directory_uri
>
> Try something like get_home_path() :
>   https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_home_path

That's incorrect.
You need to use the get_stylesheet_directory() function instead of get_stylesheet_directory_uri().

```
echo file_put_contents(get_stylesheet_directory().'/file.txt','test');
```

Should print 4